# How to compare sql:variable with NULL within XQuery

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, xquery

I have this stored procedure which receives a `@Value` parameter. I need to use that value to filter some data, or to ignore the filtering, if the parameter value is `NULL`.

Using DML only would be as simple as

```
WHERE @Value IS NULL OR Value = @Value
```

But I don't know how to use the same idea inside the XQuery expression. Right now, I have a code similar to this:

```
DECLARE @Value  AS VARCHAR(100) = 'f7fc6b6c-bb1b-4961-bb94-1053500436ac'

SELECT          Form.FormType,
                FormData         .value('(/*/Created)[1]'   , 'date'        ) Created,
                FormDataItem.this.value('@Source'           , 'varchar(100)') Source,
                FormDataItem.this.value('@Value'            , 'varchar(100)') Value,
                FormDataItem.this.value('@Text'             , 'varchar(100)') Text
FROM            Form    WITH    (NOLOCK)
CROSS APPLY     Form.FormData.nodes('//*[
                (
                    (sql:variable("@Value")  = "" and @Value != "") or
                    (sql:variable("@Value") != "" and @Value  = sql:variable("@Value"))
                )]') FormDataItem(this)
```

I could avoid this problem by:

- setting that `@Value` as an empty string literal if the value is null, or
- using some dynamic approach to craft the XQuery expression and execute it with `sp_executesql`

but I would like to avoid that.

Can you advise how am I supposed to compare a `sql:variable` to a `NULL` value inside a XQuery?

Comment: Can this be achieved with [exist()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189869.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)?

Comment: It's not very intuitive since no explicit sequences are involved, but [`empty(sql:variable("@Value"))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186394) should work.

Comment: @JeroenMostert you're right, `empty` works well for this case; make that an answer and I'll close this question. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `@Value` is a T-SQL variable, [`empty(sql:variable("@Value"))`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/ms186394) is `true` precisely when `@Value` is `NULL` (empty strings don't qualify).